# AngularJS - Getting the next sibling scope in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Given this very simplistic markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" item>
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('item', function()
{
    return function(scope, element, attrs)
    {


    }
})
```

Say on a click event, I want to get the next item's scope and do something. I can either use `scope.$$nextSibling()` or `element.next().scope()`.

Is there an advantage/disadvantage of using either? Or is there a better way of getting the next sibling's scope?

Comment: `element.next().scope()` provides a better context, but would you elaborate on why you need to do this? I don't think either option is a great choice.

Comment: You can have a parent controller hold an array of all the scopes, accessible from the children

Comment: @MattWay, thanks for the reply. I actually come across this problem quite a few times. Say that I have a list of items. And then on clicking one of them, I want the next nth to also be selected, or modified or something.

Comment: @Kousha Then you should do that in a parent controller.

Comment: You can just use eventing... to notify the subscriber when something happens. In a good design you should be restricted working on your own scope, not the scope of anybody else... You can expose the event on the sibling feature and that feature can respond to the event doing something on its own scope when it happens.

Comment: @PSL, so I could for instance `$broadcast` the `$index` of the clicked scope, and the nth next indices will answer that call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do like this 
in the scope, call $rootScope.$broadcast('SOME_CHANGE_IN_SCOPE',...);
in sibling scope, call $scope.$on('SOME_CHANGE_IN_SCOPE',...)
 you can of course wrap data in the event, check angularjs doc for more details

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you should never use any angular variables that begin with `$$`. They are meant for internal implementation and are not guaranteed to stay around from release to release.